# Font size does not change in LaTeX

Tags: fontsize

I am trying to change the font size for a latex document with a table, but it does not seem to work. I have tried document classes "book" and "article". Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=30pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Integrationstabelle – Mechanik II}
\date{Juni 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\centering
Allgemeine Formel: $f \cdot S \cdot s \cdot \frac{l}{K}$ \\ 



$f$ – Integrationskoeffizient \\
$S$ – repräsentativer Wert erster Schnittgrösse \\
$s$ – repräsentativer Wert zweiter Schnittgrösse \\
$l$ – Stablänge \\
$K$ – Steifigkeit ($EA$, $EI$, $GA_v$ etc.) \\


\newpage

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4.5}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
        
        \toprule
        
        {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 2ex 2ex 10ex,valign=m]{images/length.png}}
        & {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 5ex 0ex 2ex,valign=m]{images/rectangle_red.png}} 
        & {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 4.9ex 0ex 2.1ex,valign=m]{images/half_left_triangle_red.png}} 
        & {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 5ex 0ex 2ex,valign=m]{images/half_right_triangle_red.png}} 
        & {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 5ex 0ex 2ex,valign=m]{images/full_triangle_red.png}}
        & {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 1.7ex 0ex 2.7ex,valign=m]{images/shifted_full_triangle_red.png}}
        & {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 5ex 0ex 2ex,valign=m]{images/trapezium_red.png}} \\
        
        \midrule
        
        {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 5ex 2ex 2ex,valign=m]{images/rectangle_blue.png}} & $1sS$ & $\frac{1}{2}sS$ & $\frac{1}{2}sS$ & $\frac{1}{2}sS$ & $\frac{1}{2}sS$ & $\frac{1}{2}s(S_l+S_r)$ \\
        
        {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 4.9ex 2ex 2.1ex,valign=m]{images/half_left_triangle_blue.png}} & $\frac{1}{2}sS$ & $\frac{1}{3}sS$ & $\frac{1}{6}sS$ & $\frac{1}{4}sS$ & $\frac{1}{6}sS \left( 1+\frac{a}{l} \right)$ & $\frac{1}{6}s(S_l+2S_r)$ \\
        
        {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 5ex 2ex 2ex,valign=m]{images/half_right_triangle_blue.png}} & $\frac{1}{2}sS$ & $\frac{1}{6}sS$ & $\frac{1}{3}sS$ & $\frac{1}{4}sS$ & $\frac{1}{6}sS \left( 1+\frac{b}{l} \right)$ & $\frac{1}{6}s(2S_l+S_r)$ \\
        
        {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 5ex 2ex 2ex,valign=m]{images/full_triangle_blue.png}} & $\frac{1}{2}sS$ & $\frac{1}{4}sS$ & $\frac{1}{4}sS$ & $\frac{1}{3}sS$ & $\begin{aligned} \frac{sS}{12} & \frac{l}{b} \left( 3 - \frac{4a^2}{l^2} \right) \\ & \text{für} \,\, a < l/2 \end{aligned}$ & $\frac{1}{4}s(S_l+S_r)$ \\
        
        {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 1.7ex 2ex 2.7ex,valign=m]{images/shifted_full_triangle_blue.png}} & $\frac{1}{2}sS$ & $\frac{1}{6}sS \left( 1+\frac{c}{l} \right)$ & $\frac{1}{6}sS \left( 1+\frac{d}{l} \right)$ & $\begin{aligned}
        \frac{sS}{12} & \frac{l}{d} \left( 3 - \frac{4c^2}{l^2} \right) \\
        & \text{für} \,\, c < l/2 \end{aligned}$ & $\begin{aligned} \frac{sS}{6} \frac{l^2}{ad} & \left(\frac{2a}{l} - \frac{a^2}{l^2} - \frac{c^2}{l^2} \right) \\ & \text{für} \,\, a > c \end{aligned}$ & $\begin{aligned} \frac{1}{6} s \bigg[ & S_l \left( 1+\frac{d}{l} \right) \\ &+S_r \left( 1+\frac{c}{l} \right) \bigg] \end{aligned}$ \\
        
        {\includegraphics[width=0.11\textwidth,margin=0pt 5ex 2ex 2ex,valign=m]{images/trapezium_blue.png}} & $\frac{1}{2}(s_l+s_r)S$ & $\frac{1}{6}(s_l+2s_r)S$ & $\frac{1}{6}(2s_l+s_r)S$ & $\frac{1}{4}(s_l+s_r)S$ & $\begin{aligned} \frac{1}{6} S \bigg[ & s_l \left( 1+\frac{b}{l} \right) \\ &+s_r \left( 1+\frac{a}{l} \right) \bigg] \end{aligned}$ & $\begin{aligned} \frac{1}{6} \big[ & s_l(2S_l+S_r) \\ &+s_r(S_l+2S_r)  \big] \end{aligned}$ \\
        
        \bottomrule
        
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The standard classes only support 10, 11, and 12 pt sizes. Use the `fontsize` package to choose arbitrary sizes.

Comment: Do you mean change the fontsize for only the text in the table?

Comment: Thank you. I got the package and it worked!

Comment: No, I meant in general. I had not known, that font size could not be higher than 12pt for the above mentioned classes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comments.

Comment: I agree. Thanks!